# What does "in pipeline" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

[image]

According to a dictionary, "in pipeline" means "already been planned or begun". But I am not sure if it's what it means in this graph. Does "In Pipeline" mean preparing/planning to become one of its customers?

Comment: The context of that graph includes the text that comes with it. It's hard for any of us to judge what is meant by it without knowing what the article I presume it is embedded in actually says.

Comment: Where is the graph from?  I looks to me like what's being referred to is the "sales pipeline", which is the process of actively converting a potential customer into an actual customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on the specifics of this graph, lacking any meaningful content.

I would say, however, that this expression uses ***pipeline*** to mean a process with an ordered start-to-finish sequence of steps. For something to be ***in pipeline***, an expression we can take to have an elided *the*, it is part way through such a process.